# Apache NiFi - Storing and Access to dynamic data

Tags: apache-nifi

I am a really beginer in Apache NiFi and I am trying to find the best way to do the following process.

I have an API that exposes an endpoint that provides me a token for next requests (available for few hours). I would like to store this token for general purpose, because I need other flows accessing to this token.

I would prefer not using Files or external Databases, so  I was wondering about using variables... but honestly... no idea if this is the best way.

So far, I know how to connect with the API, (InvokeHTTP), and getting the token (EvaluateJsonPath), but I don't know how to store and where (Variable?) and how to use it in another flow.

Current flow so far:

Store Token: GenerateFlowFile -> InvokeHTTP ->EvaluateJsonPath -> ??

New request using token: GenerateFlowFile -> InvokeHTTP (Here I need to access the token)

Can anyone help me?

Thank u so much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look into using the DistributedMapCache controller service.

The flow would be something like...

GenerateFlowFile -> InvokeHTTP ->EvaluateJsonPath -> PutDistributedMapCache

GenerateFlowFile -> FetchDistributedMapCache -> InvokeHTTP

Answer (score 0):

DistributedMapCacheServer
is used to set up in memory cache

DistributedMapCacheClientService
is used as sdk to put and fetch cache

STEPS

1. setup distributed map cache server (with default values)
2. setup distributed map cache client service with default values and "serverhostname" as "localhost"
3. add PutDistributedMapCache to upload token to cache use static value or attribute in "cache Entry Identifier" this will act as the key for cache value
4. add FetchDistributedMapCache use the same value in "cache Entry Identifier" remember its the key to lookup
5. set max length to put in attribute to desired length of cache value
6. the Fetch process will rewrite flow file with cache value if "Put Cache Value In Attribute" is not set